# How to type an object's key to accept a types's toString() parameters (if present) and another key to accept the type's instance itself?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to define a well typed function that accepts an object with two keys:

1. `stringable` with type, `T` that has a `toString` method
2. `toStringArgs` the parameters that may be needed by `T`'s `toString` method

Internally, the function calls the instance's `toString` method with the supplied arguments while providing good type hinting.

My attempt:

```js
interface ToString<T = unknown> {
  toString(...args: T[]): string
}

function callToString<T extends ToString>(o: { stringable: T, toStringArgs?: Parameters<T['toString']> }) {
  return o.stringable.toString(o.toStringArgs);
}
```

This works for the most part but in scenarios where `toString` takes no arguments, it's redundant to provide `toStringArgs: []`. I have been unsuccessful in conditionally making `toStringArgs` required only when `toString` takes no one or more arguments.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDKYqgOYA8qyAvMgK4gDWI6A7iAHzIDeAUMsmFjvgBQA6IXCh4AzgC40AbQC6ASiljeIPGwC%20bNjEoIwwdCGQI4AG1MZsuVUWQQAHpBAATMWh7W8jPuiktkyp5wAEamEFKoADRcHvgAgqJiAPxSAAoicAC2EJBQYkTSAOTcVviFsszq8qwcyFA55FBG6AKB%20CFhAiUqeD5dsaoJ4vIA3BpabCbmlj187Jxtqh3hNZyc3Z58cEo90cFSIOSZwdDV82uc9WCNRnDIANTIAET3Tw-IwbWcmt-RG-GJKTSJ4ARie0SeACYnrJkAB6OHIACSIAAbmZgM5kHwHAAHCB6CDORRoACe%20OQhUWeEKyGAbloYGQcDEYmAeBAyxiXHJKEKh2O0EKAj4kIAzJDIfINNLJmYLANeudqcs-F8YqVVFsdp49gcjicoGd1ZcGk1me8Xm9Hp8Lj9kOo-oqhpJkMCwdFIbCEcgAGoYrE4%20z4wnEmXICZTBWapW1FWhFbndaKvjGi6m67mp5PdX2x0anouoHexH%200yY7F4gmQYkfchM%20rOSjOODgcNAA)

Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's distracting that you're using a method named `toString()` here, since [everything nonnullish has one of these methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), and none of them should *require* an argument, so the solution here would be to just make it optional, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbl1Ew).  Unless you're *intentionally* doing this, you should probably change the method name to something else to avoid distractions.

Comment: (see prev comment) Assuming we can change `toString()` to `stringify()` without changing the intent of your question, then [does this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAxL8N) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! The use of `toString` in `ToString` interface is very intentional since the the end user may pass a custom object with `toString` requiring mandatory param.

Comment: I modified [your approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAxL8N) to get rid of the second generic Param `B` on the function, along with the `as` type assertion. Do you see any issues with doing so? [TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WYQ2bW).

Comment: I don't think we've communicated effectively; let me try again. If any object in JavaScript has a `toString()` method that *requires* an argument, you are going to have a bad time.  JavaScript expects all objects to have a `toString()` method which serializes an object without needing an argument.  JavaScript will coerce things to string by calling `toString()` with no arguments.  So your code will likely cause random runtime errors in things as benign as console logging.  You are colliding with `toString()` and unless you have a *very* good reason, you should pick a new method name.

Comment: Put another way: unless you'd like to have a conversation about the name "`toString`", then you should change the name in this question to remove the distraction, and feel free to use whatever name you want in your own code base.  I will disengage now, unless that happens. Good luck!

Comment: In my use-case, the end-user has the onus of defining a coercion "safe" (i.e. no mandatory arguments) `toString` method. However, if their definition of `toString` needs mandatory arguments, I try to provide appropriate type safety/hinting around that. If they `console.log` such an instance which fails during runtime - it's on them.